# Yii2 get message in custom error view

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to make a custom error page in Yii2 advanced template. I was checking the following doc:
[Handling Errors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html)

So I created `actionError()` in SiteController.

I was able to get the `$exception` with following:

```
$exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
```

But i couldn't get the `$name` and `$message`.

From the `$exception` I got following:

```
yii\web\NotFoundHttpException Object
(
    [statusCode] => 404
    [message:protected] => Page not found.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0

    ... (more lines here) ...

    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

From here I see that I can get status code by `$exception->statusCode`, but can't access the message. How to fetch and pass both status code and message to view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property `message` is `protected`. Use `getMessage()` function to get the value:

```
$exceptionMessage = $exception->getMessage();
```